# Cases occurring in both A and B , listing the case twice

Tags: sql

I have a table that have two fields - Case and Room.  A Case can have multiple Rooms associated with it.
I would like to select only the cases that have Rooms 2 and 3 associated with them.
In my output I would need both the Case and the Room fields with Case 
listed twice since it is in Two Rooms - 
 [image]

When I am using the following code I am getting only the Case listed once, since I am Grouping on it.

```
SELECT Case 
FROM AGTS
WHERE Room in ('2','3')
GROUP BY Case
HAVING COUNT(distinct Room) = 2.
```

Is there a way that I can get the output with the Case occurring twice as is shown in the Snapshot and I would also like to include the column Room along with Client.

Regards,
Rishi

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM agts a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Case FROM AGTS 
    WHERE Room in ('2','3') 
    GROUP BY Case 
    HAVING COUNT(distinct Room) = 2) AS b ON a.case = b.case
WHERE a.Room IN ('2', '3')
```

*Avoid using reserved words such as `case` for your columns*

Comment: Hi Arun,  Thank you for the statment, I was able to get my results with its help.  I also tried putting max(Room) Room1 and min(Room) Room2 in my select statement along with Case and it also gave me the Room names, though I had them all in one row. (Case , Room1, Room2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original rows, then I often recommend `exists`:

```
select a.*
from agts a
where a.room in (2, 3) and
      exists (select 1
              from agts a2
              where a2.case = a.case and
                    a2.room in (2, 3) and
                    a2.room <> a.room
             );
```

If you just want the cases, I like the aggregation approach that you are using.

Comment: Hi Gordon,  Thank you, I was able to get my results with the suggested query.